# Android Back Key Issue

Tags: java, android, performance, andengine, logcat

I'm developing a game via Andengine for Android. I have big problem. When I open my game first time, it's opening well. And when I press back key button(which is on device, pyhsical button), the app is closing. But it mustn't be close. And here is the LogCat:

http://s27.postimg.org/3mhwb3j2b/Capture.png

And when I try to open app again, it is opening black blank scene.

PLS help!

Comment: Hi I can't open the link you gave (site blocked in work). Have you managed the full app lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html and remember, at some point when exited Android itself will kill an activity if it needs the space. You don't have 100% control over this. You could try and Override the onKeyDown button. Edit: beaten to it by @Gooziec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to override `onKeyDown` and block BACK button

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        return true;

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

That should prevent user from exit App with Back button

Answer (score 1):

You should override the onBackPressed function, and do what ever implementation you like. Usually a pause of the game is common with a dialog to quit or continue is used.

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed()
{}
```